# Order table Database design

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm in need of some help with the database design of order table of a shopping cart for online food ordering system. I have a design below. Tables about which I'm Concerned  are order_details and order. Basically what is going to happen is user selects foods from restaurant menus and will place order, User details are stored in the user table (which is not shown in the image).

*This is my first attempt, I was never good at Database. So please take it easy if you fill that the question is way too low for this site.*

And my questions are:

- Are the tables good enough?
- Do I need to add any more fields?
- And one more question I need to store multiple addresses of users(user can have multiple shipping address) how can I handle this?

  https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCYBi.jpg

**Note** The `item_price` table in the image is not i use. Please ignore that table while answering. Thanks

Comment: Looks pretty good.  `menu_category_item` is a little unclear, it implies something about categorization; I'd consider "menu_item".  If `restaurant_facilities` has a one-to-one relationship with `restaurants`, I'd leave them in a single wide table, but I'm not a fan of horizontal partitioning.  You'll probably want `price` and `tax` on `order_details`; some places charge different taxes for food vs alcohol, for example.

Comment: @JonofAllTrades `menu_category_item` contains menuId, ItemID, RestaurantID, categoryID, Price as same same item can belong to different restaurants with different prices. Yes `restaurant_facilities` has one-to-one relationship with `restaurants`. And should I move Tax, Discount, Total, Additional Charges to order_details? or Only Tax and Total?

Comment: Yes, I can see that.  `order_details` should definitely include `unit_price`, `total_price`, and `tax`; I'd leave them in `orders` too, it's denormalization, but a very common and reasonable exception.

Comment: `discount` is a tough call; do you expect most discounts to be off of a specific item, or off of a whole ticket?  For the greatest flexibility, I'd make discounts a type of menu item.  A person's order may include 1) Steak, $20 and 2) Salad, $5 and 3) Free Salad with any meal on Tuesdays, -$5.  The nice thing about this is that it easily handles cases like this where a discount depends on a collection rather than a single line item.

Comment: @JonofAllTrades Basically discount will be off of a whole ticket, but I can see your point and its seems good to me also for future, but can you please tell me how can I implement this in current design?should I move discount to `menu_category_item`

Comment: Your question is really a combination of two kinds of questions.  The first kind is about the quality of the design, namely whether your table design is going to facilitate your operations.  The second kind is analysis questions, namely whether the business really works the way your design assumes it does.  You need to consider the second kind first, and we can't really help you.  Your restaurants could work differently than the ones we have encountered.

Comment: @WalterMitty So, what you personally recommend to do?  should i go with the design?

Answer (score 2):

And again ;) I recommend that too often these days.

The Data Model Resource Book, Volume 1.

Order management, address management - solved, problems explained, well documented. Complex but you can simplify - just reading it will really help you understand the problems at hand.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are many problems in your design , but the most important ones according to the order functionality your are more worried about:

why `item` and `item_price` are separate tables? and why the `order_details` is not linked to `item`? you should provide a table for `orders` which is holding general data about each order, and a `order_details` which describe order items in multiple rows. each record of this table should be linked to an `item` and a record of `order` . in fact the relation between order and item is many to many and the order_details is the relating table.

to provide multiple addresses for each user, define a `user_address` table which stores all users' addresses, and link orders to `user_addresses` instead of `users`.

Comment: Item_price table is removed, and its not in use, sorry it was included in image, order_details is linked with item through menu_category_item, read my above comments if you need better understanding

Comment: @user92961 : So you should provide more details about the project definition and update the attached image if you want new visitors to help you better. according to your comments , I don't see any special problem in your design, and for the case of discounts, it deeply depends on your project definition and requirements, as I told at first

Comment: @user92961 thanks for your help..will try to update the image..as soon as i get the required rep to post images I will edit my question with the image